# tdbloader2 fails with classpath error

Tags: java, rdf, jena, tdb

When I run the following command:

```
bin/tdbloader2 --loc=/store/data/here /seed/data/serverfault-dump.nt
```

And the response I get is:

```
10:52:31 -- TDB Bulk Loader Start
10:52:31 Data phase
Error: Could not find or load main class com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.store.bulkloader2.CmdNodeTableBuilder
```

Which is most likely caused by a problem with my environment variables, somewhere, of something. The problem is, I don't often work with Java and so I don't know enough to know how to figure out what that class cannot be found.

How do make tdbloader2 find the appropriate class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had forgotten to set the JENAROOT path variable.

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tools/

> An environment variable JENAROOT is used by all the command line tools to
>   configure the class path automatically for you. You can set this up as follows:
>
> On Linux / Mac
>
> export JENAROOT=the directory you downloaded Jena to export
>   PATH=$PATH:$JENAROOT/bin On Windows
>
> SET JENAROOT=the directory you downloaded Jena to SET
>   PATH=%PATH%;%JENAROOT%\bat

Comment: I'm having the same issue currently on a Mac. Still getting the same error after setting up JENAROOT. Anything else that would cause the same behavior. [Asked Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49949842/how-do-i-interact-with-apache-jena-locally)

Comment: For anyone trying to use this in the future, I am not really good with windows Powershell. But using tdb2_tdbloader as described in https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb2/tdb2_cmds.html doesn't work in Powershell for some reason. Switching to CMD does work however after setting JENA_ROOT.

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum you need to set the `TDBROOT` environment variable to the directory containing your TDB download.  This will be the directory above `bin` as some of the scripts use `${TDBROOT}/bin/foo` to launch other scripts

The script attempts to automatically construct a valid class path by calling the `tdb_path` script which calls either `make_classpath_mvn` or `make_classpath` depending on your environment.  If you run the `tdb_path` script directly you can see if it generates a sane looking class path or not (or add what it does generate to your question if the output doesn't provide anything helpful).

Comment: OK, so I actually realized that I hadn't even set up my JENAROOT variable, which all other fuseki / jena related scripts variables inherits from