# How do I interact with Apache Jena locally? - MacOS

Tags: macos, jena, semantic-web, fuseki

I may just be going at this wrong, but I am not sure how to interact with Apache Jena on my computer. I think my main question revolves around where I store files and how I run them.

I use Atom editor and work in Python and Javascript normally. My goal here is to get a handle of how Jena and Fuseki work then potentially using Fuseki for the backend of a web app.

The tutorial, [An Introduction to RDF and the Jena RDF API](https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html), links to [Java files](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-core/src-examples/jena/examples/rdf/Tutorial01.java). Where do I store this file on my desktop and how can I run it?

While my question is about setting up my workspace/environment, I would appreciate feedback on more appropriate technologies.

---

Based on this [tutorial](http://staff.um.edu.mt/cabe2/lectures/webscience/docs/jena.pdf) I've gotten my workspace set up. I've [removed the package identifier from my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402759/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-classdemo).

Now I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/jena/rdf/model/ModelFactory at 
Tutorial01.main(Tutorial01.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I think it's a JENAROOT Issue. I think I'm [setting it and adding it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177971/tdbloader2-fails-with-classpath-error/28181902#28181902) to the path correctly. It's also mentioned [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tools/), but I haven't been able to troubleshoot it yet.

Anybody can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why just don't use Fuseki as an SPARQL endpoint: `localhost:3030` etc? About some common pitfalls: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43475640/7879193

Comment: I may end up using Fuseki, but now I just want to figure out how to get Jena up and running. Based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402759/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-classdemo) I removed the package identifier from my code. Now I've identified as an issue with JENAROOT or the CLASSPATH. Everything compiles, but then I get an error.

Comment: I have a complete example  [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/04/10/creating-writing-and-reading-jena-tdb2-datasets/) with example code in github that may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I got help of this via the [Apache Jena support email](https://jena.apache.org/help_and_support/index.html). I think I must have caused an issue by changing the environmental variables for Jena upon first use.

Based on a script I received from a community member I ran a script named jenaJarsScript.sh in terminal:

```
unset JARS
for f in $JENA_HOME/lib/*.jar
do
  JARS=$JARS:$f
  export JARS
done
```

I then added $JARS to my classpath - now I can compile and run code without an issue.

**Note:** I'm not sure if this is the best way to set this up, but it works for me.